# Swift Async let with loop

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I want to get data in parallel. I found an example to call API in parallel but I want to store `async let variables` with loop.

Async let example. However, this example doesn't use a loop.

```swift
async let firstPhoto = downloadPhoto(named: photoNames[0])
async let secondPhoto = downloadPhoto(named: photoNames[1])
async let thirdPhoto = downloadPhoto(named: photoNames[2])

let photos = await [firstPhoto, secondPhoto, thirdPhoto]
show(photos)
```

I want to do something like the following.

```swift
let items = photoNames.map({ photo in
    async let item = downloadPhoto(named: photo)
    return item
}) 
let photos = await items
show(photos)
```

Comment: Does the backend not have an API for downloading multiple photos at once?

Comment: Backend doesn't have one

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use a task group. See [Tasks and Task Groups](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID642) section of the *The Swift Programming Language: Concurrency* (which would appear to be where you got your example).

One can use [`withTaskGroup(of:returning:body:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/3814991-withtaskgroup/) to create a task group to run tasks in parallel, but then collate all the results together at the end.

E.g. here is an example that creates child tasks that return a tuple of “name” and ”image”, and the group returns a combined dictionary of those name strings with their associated image values:

```
func downloadImages(names: [String]) async -> [String: UIImage] {
    await withTaskGroup(
        of: (String, UIImage).self,
        returning: [String: UIImage].self
    ) { [self] group in
        for name in names {
            group.addTask { await (name, downloadPhoto(named: name)) }
        }

        var images: [String: UIImage] = [:]

        for await result in group {
            images[result.0] = result.1
        }

        return images
    }
}
```

Or, more concisely:

```swift
func downloadImages(names: [String]) async -> [String: UIImage] {
    await withTaskGroup(of: (String, UIImage).self) { [self] group in
        for name in names {
            group.addTask { await (name, downloadPhoto(named: name)) }
        }

        return await group.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
    }
}
```

They run in parallel:

[image]

But you can extract them from the dictionary of results:

```swift
let stooges = ["moe", "larry", "curly"]
let images = await downloadImages(names: stooges)

imageView1.image = images["moe"]
imageView2.image = images["larry"]
imageView3.image = images["curly"]
```

---

Or if you want an array sorted in the original order, just build an array from the dictionary:

```swift
func downloadImages(names: [String]) async -> [UIImage] {
    await withTaskGroup(of: (String, UIImage).self) { [self] group in
        for name in names {
            group.addTask { await (name, downloadPhoto(named: name)) }
        }

        let dictionary = await group.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
        return names.compactMap { dictionary[$0] }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use the `returning` argument?

Comment: In this case, the return type can inferred, so it’s not needed.

Answer (score 4):

[`Channel`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md)s and [`Heap`](https://github.com/kodecocodes/swift-algorithm-club/blob/master/Heap/Heap.swift) are the most recent tools, as of the time of this answer update, which provide an order-maintaining solution.

```swift
import AsyncAlgorithms

let photos = await Array(photoNames.mapWithTaskGroup(downloadPhoto))
```

```swift
import AsyncAlgorithms
import HeapModule

public extension Sequence where Element: Sendable {
  /// Transform a sequence asynchronously, and potentially in parallel.
  /// - Returns: An `AsyncSequence` which returns transformed elements, in their original order,
  /// as soon as they become available.
  func mapWithTaskGroup<Transformed: Sendable>(
    priority: TaskPriority? = nil,
    _ transform: @escaping @Sendable (Element) async -> Transformed
  ) -> AsyncChannel<Transformed> {
    let channel = AsyncChannel<Transformed>()
    Task { await mapWithTaskGroup(channel: channel, transform) }
    return channel
  }

  /// Transform a sequence asynchronously, and potentially in parallel.
  /// - Returns: An `AsyncSequence` which returns transformed elements, in their original order,
  /// as soon as they become available.
  func mapWithTaskGroup<Transformed: Sendable>(
    priority: TaskPriority? = nil,
    _ transform: @escaping @Sendable (Element) async throws -> Transformed
  ) -> AsyncThrowingChannel<Transformed, Error> {
    let channel = AsyncThrowingChannel<Transformed, Error>()
    Task {
      do {
        try await mapWithTaskGroup(channel: channel, transform)
      } catch {
        channel.fail(error)
      }
    }
    return channel
  }
}

// MARK: - private
private protocol AsyncChannelProtocol<Element> {
  associatedtype Element
  func send(_: Element) async
  func finish()
}

extension AsyncChannel: AsyncChannelProtocol { }
extension AsyncThrowingChannel: AsyncChannelProtocol { }

private extension Sequence where Element: Sendable {
  private func mapWithTaskGroup<Transformed: Sendable>(
    channel: some AsyncChannelProtocol<Transformed>,
    priority: TaskPriority? = nil,
    _ transform: @escaping @Sendable (Element) async throws -> Transformed
  ) async rethrows {
    typealias ChildTaskResult = Heap<Int>.ElementValuePair<Transformed>
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: ChildTaskResult.self) { group in
      for (offset, element) in enumerated() {
        group.addTask(priority: priority) {
          .init(offset, try await transform(element))
        }
      }

      var heap = Heap<ChildTaskResult>()
      var lastSentOffset = -1
      for try await childTaskResult in group {
        heap.insert(childTaskResult)
        // Send as many in-order `Transformed`s as possible.
        while heap.min()?.element == lastSentOffset + 1 {
          await channel.send(heap.removeMin().value)
          lastSentOffset += 1
        }
      }

      channel.finish()
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
import HeapModule

public extension Heap {
  /// A "`Value`" that uses an accompanying `Heap.Element` for sorting  via a `Heap`.
  /// - Note: If `Value` itself is `Comparable`, it can of course be inserted into a Heap directly.
  ///   This type is explicitly for cases where a different sorting rule is desired.
  struct ElementValuePair<Value> {
    public var element: Element
    public var value: Value
  }
}

// MARK: - public
public extension Heap.ElementValuePair {
  init(_ element: Element, _ value: Value) {
    self.init(element: element, value: value)
  }
}

// MARK: - Comparable
extension Heap.ElementValuePair: Comparable {
  public static func < (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    lhs.element < rhs.element
  }

  /// Only necessary because Comparable: Equatable. 
  public static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    fatalError()
  }
}

// MARK: - Sendable
extension Heap.ElementValuePair: Sendable where Element: Sendable, Value: Sendable { }
```

Comment: This needs some explanation. Code-only answers are not very helpful.

Comment: Your second extension is using an internal type. I think that would deserve some explanation because it looks like something that can break easily.

Answer (score -3):

If the order of result doesn't matter here, use a `TaskGroup` instead.