# Do higher order functions in Swift respect the order?

Tags: swift

Not a coding question but it's something that I couldn't find an answer to.

Do higher order functions like `.map()`, `.filter()`, `.reduce()` respect the order of given collection?

Let's assume that we have an array of integers as follows:

```swift
let arrayOfIntegers: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Will this line of code always return the same order?

```swift
arrayOfIntegers.map { $0 * 2 } // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Is it even possible to have something like `[2, 6, 10, 4, 8]`?

Comment: Depends on the collection. Arrays in Swift care about order while dictionaries do not.

Comment: Just to clarify some terminology (in case it's a symptom of an underlying misunderstanding) these qualify as "higher order functions", yes, but that doesn't really mean anything beyond "functions that take a function as an argument". There's no contractual requirements about how many times a higher order function will run the passed function, in what order, or even if it will call it at all. So you have to look at the documentation of each specific function, for each type. E.g. `SomeConcurrentContainer.map` might work differently than `Array.map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/map(_:)), [`filter(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/filter(_:)), [`reduce(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/reduce(_:_:)), and many other similar higher-order functions are all provided by the [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence) protocol. The purpose of this protocol is for defining a way to iterate through sequences of data, and it provides a wide variety of methods which are implemented in terms of that sequential access through the data.

The order in which a `Sequence` provides its data is up to it. While many types like `Array` have a natural order to them, there are other `Sequence`s which do not, like `Set` or `Dictionary`. (Note that types like this offer iteration in *some* consistent order, but the order may be arbitrary.)

The order, then, that your `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` functions will be called in depends on the iteration order of the underlying collection — but in most cases, it will simply be what you expect.

Comment: Interestingly, I just noticed that the docs for [`Array.map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/map(_:)-87c4d) don't guarantee the output order. It's kind of implied by the example, and it'll be an absolute shitshow if it ever changed, but I don't see any explicit language guaranteeing the 1-to-1 correspondence between input and output elements

Comment: @Alexander Note that `Array` itself does not actually have a `map(_:)` method — it's inherited directly from `Collection`, which refines it from `Sequence` only so far as to benefit from having a known `.count` rather than an `.underestimatedCount`. It couldn't really reasonably offer its own `map(_:)` because `map(_:)` isn't a protocol requirement of either `Sequence` or `Collection`, which means it's exclusively statically-dispatched (so if it differed from either impl., you'd get different behavior based on the static type)...

Comment: In the case of `Sequence`, the only thing it _can_ reasonably do is iterate in-order, and `Collection` couldn't reasonably change the behavior for the same reasons as `Array`: the same exact dynamic value would have different behavior based on its static type. I didn't want to complicate the answer with this info, but this is as close to a guarantee as you can get, I think.

Comment: In terms of the docs, they're inherited verbatim from `Sequence.map(_:)` — it's definitely confusing, but the docs for all of the stdlib types repeat the docs from their base type (so you see `Array.map(_:)`, [`String.map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/map(_:)-87c4v), etc.). It's not at all obvious when you're looking at the docs for `Array`, but given the original comes from `Sequence`, it's a bit more obvious why order isn't mentioned: it can't reasonably be anything _but_ in order, since `Sequence` is potentially one-pass.

Comment: (Theoretically, yes, `Sequence` could store all of the results in intermediate storage in some order other than iteration order, but doing anything _but_ storing the elements in iteration order would take more work than leaving it as-is.)

Comment: "It couldn't really reasonably offer its own map(_:) because map(_:) isn't a protocol requirement of either Sequence or Collection, which means it's exclusively statically-dispatched" True... Hypothetically, is it possible to refine the docs on an API like this? I.e. to document the stronger guarantees, while still using the same Collection-provided implementation?

Comment: Good question! I have no idea — that's largely up to Apple's doc tools. But presumably, if they're able to replicate the documentation from `Collection` onto `Array`, they could probably refine it. As far as I know, the documentation is duplicated on concrete types for convenience, so that if you're looking at something like `Array`, you can see all of the useful stuff on it; my guess is that it's possible, but time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement Itai's existing answer:

If you have this code:

```swift
let arrayOfIntegers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let result = arrayOfIntegers.map { $0 * 2 }
print(result) // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

The **result** is guaranteed<sup>* kind of</sup> to always be in that order, for the case of [`Array.map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/map(_:)-87c4d)

What's *not* guaranteed is that the **calls** to the closure will happen in any particular order. So if the closure has any side-effects, they might observe a different order. So don't do this:

```swift
let arrayOfIntegers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var sideChannel = [Int]()

let result = arrayOfIntegers.map { i -> Int in
    sideChannel.append(i * 10) // ⚠️ Don't put side effects in calls to `map` like this.
    return i * 2
}
print(result) // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
print(sideChannel) // [10, 20, 30, 40, 50], but the order is not guaranteed
```

That's mostly a theoretical concern, however. It's very unlikely to change. Still, don't rely on it.

* <sup>The example in the docs implies the ordering is guaranteed, but I don't see any explicit language guaranteeing the 1-to-1 correspondence between input and output elements. However, changing the ordering would be an absolute shitshow, because of all the existing code that depend on it.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Other people are telling what the situation is, for unordered collections, but there are no type-safe guarantees regardless of the orderliness of the sequence. It just happens that everybody writes things* in a way that preserves order coming from the [iterator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol), because it's useful and expected.

Here's an example, where the parameter is totally disregarded, and the output's order is not deterministic. The language provides the freedom for this.

```swift
extension Collection {
  func ️<️>(_: ️) -> [Element] {
    indices.shuffled().map { self[$0] }
  }
}
```

```swift
(1...5).️("")
(1...5).️ { }
(1...5).️ { $0 * 2 }
```

---

* Note: this breaks down for async sequences. The standard there is not to preserve order, unless the work is being done sequentially—[parallelism requires more effort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69964189/652038).